# Linq Sub-Select

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

How do I write a sub-select in LINQ.

If I have a list of customers and a list of orders I want all the customers that have no orders.

This is my pseudo code attempt:

```
    var  res = from c in customers 
where c.CustomerID ! in (from o in orders select o.CustomerID) 
select c
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about:

```
var res = from c in customers 
          where !orders.Select(o => o.CustomerID).Contains(c.CustomerID)
          select c;
```

Another option is to use:

```
var res = from c in customers
          join o in orders 
               on c.CustomerID equals o.customerID 
               into customerOrders
          where customerOrders.Count() == 0
          select c;
```

Are you using LINQ to SQL or something else, btw? Different flavours may have different "best" ways of doing it

Comment: Isn't using Any() instead of Count() slightly better in terms of readability?  Was reading Bill Wagner's More Effective C# and this was one of the recommendations.

Comment: Yes, quite possibly. Lots of ways of doing it. Arguably it would be nice to have an Empty() or None() extension method which is the opposite of Any() too...

Answer (score 6):

If this is database-backed, try using navigation properties (if you have them defined):

```
var res = from c in customers
          where !c.Orders.Any()
          select c;
```

On Northwind, this generates the TSQL:

```
SELECT /* columns snipped */
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[CustomerID] = [t0].[CustomerID]
    ))
```

Which does the job quite well.

Answer (score -1):

```
            var result = (from planinfo in db.mst_pointplan_info
                                                           join entityType in db.mst_entity_type
                                                           on planinfo.entityId equals entityType.id
                                                           where planinfo.entityId == entityId
                                                           && planinfo.is_deleted != true
                                                           && planinfo.system_id == systemId
                                                           && entityType.enity_enum_id == entityId
                                                           group planinfo by planinfo.package_id into gplan
                                                           select new PackagePointRangeConfigurationResult
                                                           {
                                                               Result = (from planinfo in gplan
                                                                         select new PackagePointRangeResult
                                                                         {
                                                                             PackageId = planinfo.package_id,
                                                                             PointPlanInfo = (from pointPlanInfo in gplan
                                                                                              select new PointPlanInfo
                                                                                              {
                                                                                                  StartRange = planinfo.start_range,
                                                                                                  EndRange = planinfo.end_range,
                                                                                                  IsDiscountAndChargeInPer = planinfo.is_discount_and_charge_in_per,
                                                                                                  Discount = planinfo.discount,
                                                                                                  ServiceCharge = planinfo.servicecharge,
                                                                                                  AtonMerchantShare = planinfo.aton_merchant_share,
                                                                                                  CommunityShare = planinfo.community_share
                                                                                              }).ToList()
                                                                         }).ToList()
                                                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var  res = (from c in orders where c.CustomerID == null
               select c.Customers).ToList();
```

or Make Except()