# Linq - How to do two select queries?

Tags: c#, linq

```
SELECT userid FROM userTable 
WHERE userid in (select writeuserid FROM boardTable)
```

C# LINQ expressions, how to use a query?

I have been using EF4. 
userTable, boardTable is connected to the DbContext.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. And more important, _did you tried anything so far_? You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Do you have a model? For example, is userTable represented by a class?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418609/how-to-do-subquery-in-linq

Answer (score 4):

Why not have two different LINQ queries, so that your inner query **doesn't execute for each iteration** of the outer query.

```
var query1 = (from t in dbContext.boardTable
            select t.writeuserid).ToArray();

var query2 = from r in dbContext.userTable
             where query1.Contains(r.userid)
             select r.userid;
```

If your situation is as simple as in the question then you cause [join in linq](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527819/linq-sub-select  or check this one too

Comment: +1 just for spend more effort than OP to solve this problem..

Comment: Using ToArray() may be a bit dangerous if the amount of data is very large, since it will cause EF to materialize the entire array. A join may be more suited for that purpose.

Comment: @PabloRomeo, actually I wasn't sure about the exact requirement of the OP, so presented him/her with the above option, also added a link for joins in linq

Answer (score 1):

Assume in here you use Entity FrameWork, so you can use [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) to get the result, below is to use the lambda expression:

```
var result = dbContext.Users.Join(dbContext.Boards, 
                                  user => user.UserId, 
                                  board => board.WriteUserId,
                                  (u, b) => u.UserId);
```

Comment: A little bit explanation would be great for OP, IMO..

Answer (score 1):

why not using join?

```
var result = (from u in dbcontext.userTable 
join u1 in dbcontext.boardTable on u.userid equals u1.writeuserid
select u.userid).FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
 // do anything else
else
 // user not exists
```